# Is there a way to include local svg files into Storybook that I am using with a custom Angular Library?

Tags: angular, svg, webpack, angular-material, storybook

I can't get any of my local svg files to show up in Storybook.

I have pushed a new rule to Storybook's webpack config file in main.js under .storybook folder and am using the svg-inline-loader for the svg files (has been installed).

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.svg$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
  }],
});
```

I have tried editing the package.json to allow the -s flag and passed in a param that points directly to my assets folder containing the svg files.

I get 404 returns on the network inpector

```
Request URL: http://localhost:6006/assets/icon.svg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

Have tried creating a custom.d.ts

```
declare module "*.svg" {
const content: string;
export default content;
}
declare module "svg-inline-angular"
```

And tried adding it to tsconfig.json in the .storybook folder but no luck either

The latest thing I tried was adding `import '!svg-inline-loader!../filepath_to_assets`, but this also came up empty

I have done this on a normal application, and in the angular.json file included the assets folder in the assets object array. This works for importing my svg files, but doesn't work in a library

Any ideas out there? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Storybook has loaders that are conflicting with the loader added by your custom Webpack config.

You can try [storybook-preset-inline-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-preset-inline-svg) which uses `svg-inline-loader`, or you can manually filter out the rules which are conflicting with yours.

Something like:

```
config.module.rules = [
  // Turn off the default SVG file-loader
  ...config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (/svg/.test(rule.test) && /file-loader/.test(rule.loader)) {
      return { ...rule, exclude: /\.svg$/i }
    }

    return rule
  )},
  // Add your own SVG loader
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    use: [{
      loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
    }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to '.storybook/main.js' and add to module.exports the following:
`"staticDirs":[{from:'route-to-your-assets (e.g projects/library/icons)', to: '/assets' }],`
It will copy the folder to assets